# How to create union type based on another union?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have union type

```
type UserDtoRolesType = 'U' | 'C' | 'A';
```

I want create new union type based on **UserDtoRolesType**
*'U' -> 'User'| 'C' -> 'Customer' |'A' -> 'Admin'*

What I want to get:

```
type UserRolesType = 'User' | 'Customer' | 'Admin';
```

I tried to do

```
type TRoleConverter<R> =  R extends 'U' ?
  'User' :
  R extends 'C' ?
    'Customer' :
    R extends 'A' ? 'Admin' : never;

export type TUserRole = TRoleConverter<UserDtoRolesType>;
```

This gives the desired result, but it seems cumbersome and not correct.
Is it possible to avoid hard coding this and get a new union type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Indexed Access Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) to archive this:

```
type UserDtoRolesType = 'U' | 'C' | 'A';

type UserRoleMap = {
  U:'User',
  C:'Customer',
  A:'Admin'
}

export type TUserRole = UserRoleMap[UserDtoRolesType];
```

Comment: the goal was to create a single source from which you can make another type, if you rework your version a little: [look test](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBcE8AcFNQKoGdYCcAi4D2AlLAbWJAFRngF5QByBK0AH2oGE7GqBBKgbgFgAofgGMsAOyThEKVHkIBZAIbRQlAN79QiAFwAKGlLryk1ZGioBKADTrQTHVSYBXcVgC2p0IeZPsb1Oat8Gux27AAmLgCWIgZGHOFR5vwAvvxQcKCyAJoA+gDyAEIAUgCiTMTZxJkACsXKEGRYAGaSaDKwCtC8fGnwJhjYbSRkdQDWsJBN9XCTfW0dXfywAB7QWKgSPaDEswQUGTkFJWUV1cUA2n2YuLtDcAC6XUA) , then it will turn out, then what I wanted - thanks!

Comment: easier way, thanks for the idea [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=59&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAqhApgJwEogDaILIEMAOMAvDAN4CwAUDPAFwwDkCKDANFTQML0OcCu0EAFsW7ajACCPCQBMhASzAMqAXxi4IMUJCgBuKlUQAPfCGSwoAT3yIYAFWbIAIlBDosmkgGtElkADMYKxsA+CQ0TBwCfUpjU3Mg61sHcPdbEmDEUMc0vHwAbRSUFzdIiABdXSA)

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify the code slightly like the following. But I'm not sure of any other way to improve the solution.

```js
type UserRolesType = 
  UserDtoRolesType extends infer R 
    ? R extends 'U' ? 'User' 
    : R extends 'C' ? 'Customer' 
    : R extends 'A' ? 'Admin' 
    : never 
    : never;
```

Comment: almost the same as what I tried to do, thanks, but the first answer is more satisfying